# SSB dbgen Linux - Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

I am trying to generate SSB tables and getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. During "make" I get a lot of warnings due to variable types but it seems to compile with success. I do understand that segmentation fault is due to the wrong memory access but I have not changed anything except for 4 makefile options. Make file has:

```
CC = gcc
DATABASE = DB2
MACHINE = LINUX
WORKLOAD = SSBM
```

I have already downloaded several generatos from different websites but I always get same error. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
Any ideas?

Regards, Veronika

Comment: Side question: what is `SSB`?

Comment: Oh ... my bad, probably should have posted with full name. SSB stands for Star Schema Benchmark.

Comment: I've encountered a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29451640/1593077)... Nika, did you end up managing to build and successfully run the dbgen?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue today on a Ubuntu 15.04 VM with 2GB of RAM.

Solved the problem by increasing the VM memory allocation to 16GB.